# A way to assert that a field is of a specific literal type while maintaining type invariants associated with that

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript type of the form:

```js
type MyResponseType = {
  type: "data";
  data: MyDataType;
} | {
  type: "count";
  count: number;
  pages: number;
};
```

This type is returned from one of my API endpoints. Depending on how the endpoint is called, the `type` field either has the value of `"data"` or the value of `"count"`.

The `data`, `count` and `pages` fields can only be accessed in contexts where the value of the `type` field is known. The usual way of creating such a context is by branching on it or something, like so:

```js
function handle(res: MyResponseType) {
  if(res.type === "data") {
    return res.data;
  } else {
    return [res.count, res.pages];
  }
}
```

However, I know that if I call my API in a certain way, the `MyResponseType` I get back will always have `type: "count"`, or sometimes I know it will always have `type: "data"`. Is there a way to tell the compiler what the value of the `type` field is so that I get access to the rest of the fields, without having to do a runtime check?

I know I could restructure my code to take advantage of the knowledge I have in my head, such as splitting the endpoint into two: one that always returns the count, and one that returns the data. But at this point, such a refactor is infeasible.

My first instinct was to cast as so: `res as { type: "count" }`. But of course this is too hopeful and the resulting type is just `{ type: "count" }` as is consistent with casting rules in TypeScript.

I'm hoping that I don't have to split it into several types and cast to those. I feel like there is some utility type that could be constructed for this purpose.

Comment: `MyResponseType & { type: "count" }`? https://tsplay.dev/wOrl6W